# Mean value theorem for Lebesgue integral

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let $f$ be a mesurable function and $g$ be integrable function, and $\alpha, \beta$ are real numbers such that $\alpha \leq f \leq \beta$ a.e . Prove that there exists a real number $\gamma \in [\alpha, \beta]$ such that 
>   $$\int f|g|d \mu = \gamma \int |g|d\mu.$$

I have no idea to proceed the proof. I also searched on the Internet but I got nowhere. Can anyone give me some clear hints? Thanks

Comment: Fundamental theorem of calculus might help.

Comment: Can you explane more clearly?

Answer (score 1):

Simply note

$$
\alpha \int |g|\,d\mu \leq \int f |g|\,d\mu \leq \beta \int |g|\,d\mu. 
$$
Why does this imply the claim?